# Is there a way to visualize variables in real time?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am looking for a way to plot or graph variables so I can visually see how the robot is interpreting data such as range finders.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/257/is-there-a-way-to-visualize-variables-in-real-time?/) by [mdedonato](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/86/mdedonato/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-11-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Erik Stoltenborg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/77/erik-stoltenborg/) on 2012-11-21**:
Are you using just gazebo, or ROS based gazebo?

**Comment by [Erik Stoltenborg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/77/erik-stoltenborg/) on 2012-11-21**:
If so, broadcast the data to a topic, listin to it using something like matlab and plot it.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/96/sam/) on 2012-11-27**:
Maybe you can try rxplot or rviz on ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In the short term, [rxplot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxplot) is the best approach.

Alternatively, you can write a plugin that outputs data for use with gnuplot.

Gazebo will eventually get a plotting utility, but that will not happen for a few more months.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1